# Excel VBA Code to Combine (concat) cells with If Statement and/or ContainWord

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to add VBA code which will combine cells which would be more complete together. For example, each cell which contains the word "Class" is good on its own. However, if a cell contains "Classes", it should also contain "and". Some of the cells which contain "Classes" do not contain "and". That cell which contains the associated "and" is one or two lines down below, but it is the next cell.

> Classes GE, GH, GK, GL, GN, GP,
>
> GQ and IG
>
> Class LD
>
> Class LP
>
> Classes H, HB, HC, HD, HE, HG,
>
> HI, HJ, HK, HL, HN, HP and HQ
>
> Classes E, EA, EB, EC, ED, EG and EI

The line with "Classes E, EA, EB, EC, ED, EG and EI" is good on its own as the "Classes" and "and" are in the same cell. The cell containing "Classes GE..." and the cell below it, "GQ and IG" need to now become one cell.

The code I have so far is:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord, ContainWord2, ContainWord3, ContainWord4 As String
Dim lngTotRows As Integer

lngTotRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("A1:BB" & lngTotRows)
ContainWord = "Class"
ContainWord2 = "Classes"
ContainWord3 = "and"
ContainWord4 = ","

'Delete all cells without the ContainWords
For Each cell In rng.Cells

If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing And cell.Find(ContainWord2) Is Nothing 
  And cell.Find(ContainWord3) Is Nothing And cell.Find(ContainWord4) Is 
Nothing Then cell.Clear
Next cell

    Range("A1").Select 
   
'Combine cells which have "classes" but not "and" with the subsequent cells   
 which contain "and"
 For Each cell In rng.Cells
 If InStr(cell, ContainWord2) > 0 And InStr(cell, ContainWord3) = 0 Then
```

My first task of deleting everything which did not contain those contain words works great. It's the next part I am having difficulty with. I have looked over a bunch of other threads regarding ifs and containwords and combine and InStr, but haven't been able to figure out what to do after the "Then". Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate in vba can be substituted with "&" and strings

```
    dim string1,string2 as string
    dim nextCell as range

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
      string1= cell.text
      if instr(string1, containword2) >0 and not instr(string1, containword3) >0 then
          set nextcell = activeworksheet.usedrange.find(what:=containword3, after:=cell.address, _
                     lookat:=xlpart, lookinxlformulas, _
                     search order:= xlbyrows, searchdirection:=xlnext, _
                     matchcase:=false)
          string2= nextcell.text
          cell.text= string1 & " " & string2
          nextcell.clear 
      end if

    Next cell
```

code is untested, the idea is find the next cell that contains the word "and" and concatenate it with current cell. However, there is a case where next cell could contain both "Classes" and "and", which the above code would not work on. Not sure if you have this case in your data. Let me know if you do.

Comment: This looks exactly what I am looking for, thanks. It is almost working. My watch shows that it has found "Classes G, GA, GB, GC, GD," and has stored that in the cell and string1 variables. However, I get a type mismatch when it finds the first truth in the If instr and tries to Set in the Cells.Find for the ContainWord3 (which is properly defined as "and") after the cell.address (which it properly found as $A$4). I wonder if the Strings and Ranges are mixing it up? I tried to set each of the variables as variant (I know not the best practice) to try to workaround, but still to no avail.

Comment: Ok so I figured it out - a workaround at least. The way I did it was to make the cell variable the activeCell first, then use that for the cells.find. I'm not sure 100% why that worked, but below is my code. @Middle thanks for your help!

Comment: @ejm88 Ah sorry for the late reply, good to hear you've found a solution. I think the type mismatch probably comes from using {Cells.find} instead of {Range.Find}. In vba, the cells methods and range methods are two completely types usually. I will change the code accordingly, but it's best not to touch your working code already. Check out the other solution, in theory it does the same thing but better.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a different logic in your data and therefore took a different approach: If the word "class" isn't in a cell's content then it must be appended to the previous. I also don't recommend to delete data (they took so much time to accumulate, lol:). Instead, my code below writes a new list. I placed this list on the same sheet but you could create it anywhere.

Before you try the code please set a suitable `TargetColumn` at the top of the code. I also recommend that you replace `With Activesheet` with something like `With Worksheets("My List of Classes")` which would make the code less accident prone.

```
Private Sub MergeClassList()
    ' 08 Jan 2018

    Const TargetColumn As Long = 10              ' column to write result to

    Dim Itm As String, Out As String
    Dim Sp() As String                          ' helper to insert "and"
    Dim Rt As Long                              ' Target row
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last used row
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Rt = 2                                  ' start output in row 2
        For R = 2 To Rl                         ' first data row = 2
            Itm = Trim(.Cells(R, "A").Value)
            If InStr(1, Itm, "class", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                If Len(Out) Then
                    .Cells(Rt, TargetColumn).Value = Out
                    Rt = Rt + 1
                End If
                Out = Itm
            Else
                If Len(Out) Then
                    If Right(Out, 1) <> "," Then Out = Out & ","
                    Out = Replace(Out, " and", ",") & " "
                End If
                Out = Out & Itm
                If InStr(Out, ",") And (InStr(1, Out, "and", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
                    Sp = Split(Out, ",")
                    Do
                        Out = Left(Out, Len(Out) - 1)
                    Loop Until Right(Out, 1) = ","
                    Out = Left(Out, Len(Out) - 1) & " and" & Sp(UBound(Sp))
                End If
            End If
        Next R
        If Len(Out) Then .Cells(Rt, TargetColumn).Value = Out
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```